# Could not find a required file. Name: index.js

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I start my npm it shows the below error, I also install npm globally by using this statement( npm install -g create-react-app)I make two practice project but these are number 2nd project, In the first project, I also install npm globally

```
PS E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome> cd avatarawesome
PS E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome\avatarawesome> npm start

> avatarawesome@0.1.0 start E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome\avatarawesome
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome\avatarawesome\src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! avatarawesome@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the avatarawesome@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Could you please show you folder structure in `avatarawesome`?

Comment: E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome\avatarawesome

Comment: Help me to resolve my issue pls..

Comment: I have also one question that why it is necessary to write these piece of statement before making any project (npm install -g create-react-app) or (npx create-react-app my-app)

Comment: where are you getting the demo code from?

Comment: I try my self and take help from youtube and StackOverflow

Comment: can you include the `package.json` file in the question?

Comment: if you are using TypeScript maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64720086/could-not-find-a-required-file-adding-typescript-to-react-project

Answer (score 3):

Maybe index.js is not present , check your folder correctly

Comment: Yeh, it is right but I delete the inbuilt src folder and create my own folder and in these folders, I create avatar.js file as it is the right way or wrong pls describe me.

Comment: create a file named `index.js` and import your `avatar.js` to  it  and render the index.js to the DOM

Comment: or create a `App.js` file and import all your components to it like your `avatar.js` and return it there (`App.js`),after that import your `App.js` to `index.js` and render it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I created a new src folder, it wasn't inside my cd. so it gave this error. Dragging the src folder inside the cd solved the error for me

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your js file to "index.js"

Answer (score 0):

uninstall create-react-app by `npm uninstall create-react-app`,then reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but this did not help. I just created a new react project by npx create-react-app 'project-name' and just deleted the files inside src folder. then created a new index.js. instead of deleting the src folder for the purpose of creating the react project from scratch. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I noticed I opened my src folder inside my public folder. I removed my src folder from my public folder and that solved my issue. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be you put src folder inside public folder it should be on the same level of public level

-public
-src