# Could not find a required file. - Adding TypeScript to React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to add TypeScript to an already created React app via: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript

I do everything bu get the following error when I try and start:

```
> npx react-scripts start
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: /home/karl/dev/afry/tmr-client/src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tmr-client@0.1.0 start: `npx react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tmr-client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/karl/.npm/_logs/2020-11-06T18_43_02_622Z-debug.log
```

I renamed the index.js to index.ts as stated in the guide.

Comment: Guide says to rename to `index.tsx`, not `index.ts`.

Comment: @JBallin AMAGHAWD. Post an answer I'll accept.

Comment: I'm revisiting this due to the downvotes on my answer. I've updated my answer, explaining that it's unclear to me why this isn't working. Are you sure you don't have `create-react-app` or `react-scripts` installed in a parent folder? I want to ensure you're using the latest version. Also noticed you're calling `react-scripts` directly using npx, instead of using the `start` script - but I presume this should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**TLDR**:  `npm i -D react-scripts@latest`

### Outdated react-scripts Version

I'm not sure why `index.ts` isn't working for you, it seems to be [supported](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/749a76d291d6b07681d0941eeb23112c6970d3c4/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js#L40).

The only explanation is that you're using an outdated version of `react-scripts`, which you can update by simply running `npm i -D react-scripts@latest`. More detail from [Updating to New Releases](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/):

> Create React App is divided into two packages:
>
> create-react-app is a global command-line utility that you use to
> create new projects. react-scripts is a development dependency in the
> generated projects (including this one). When you run npx
> create-react-app my-app it automatically installs the latest version
> of Create React App.
>
> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
> install -g create-react-app, please visit Getting Started to learn
> about current installation steps.
>
> Create React App creates the project with the latest version of
> react-scripts so you’ll get all the new features and improvements in
> newly created apps automatically.
>
> To update an existing project to a new version of react-scripts, open
> the changelog, find the version you’re currently on (check
> package.json in this folder if you’re not sure), and apply the
> migration instructions for the newer versions.
>
> In most cases bumping the react-scripts version in package.json and
> running npm install (or yarn install) in this folder should be enough,
> but it’s good to consult the changelog for potential breaking changes.
>
> We commit to keeping the breaking changes minimal so you can upgrade
> react-scripts painlessly.

If this is the issue, you're relying on global installation of `create-react-app` - which is not recommended given that it won't use the latest version. See note under [Quick Start](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/):

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
> install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
> using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove
> create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue today with create-react-app. The problem is the version of react-scripts as per this Git issue: [Git Reference](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5541)

A quick solution is to update react-scripts. I am using react-scripts version 4.0.3 with no issues.

A safe way to do it based on the documentation: [Create React App Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/)  would be to change the version of react-scripts in the package.json file to the most recent stable version like "react-scripts": "^4.0.3". Then, run `npm install` from the command line.

Comment: Same issue here with the most recent stable version(4.0.3)