# Unable to add typescript to a react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, react-typescript

I'm trying to add typescript to a existing react project but I'm getting an error when re-starting the server with npm start.

I'm following the steps from [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) documentation but I'm getting an error message:

[image]

The only thing I might not have right is the react.scripts versions. Here is a copy of the results thrown by npm outdated:

[image]

Also, I checked my dependencies and everything seems to be normal.

Things I have done:

- run npm update to update all react related packages
- I have deleted the node files and re install them with npm install
- I have renamed other files to .tsx including the index.js file but I get another error:

[image]

Really keen to move this project to the next level with typescript but I have been stack trying to get it to work. By the way, here are my dependencies too:

```
{
  "name": "world-budget-react-v",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "firebase": "^8.2.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scroll-restoration": "^1.0.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.6.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.3",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Any recommendations? I hope I provided as much info as possible!

Lastly, I found this answer but not sure what they mean. Anyone keen to explain maybe [Could not find a required file. - Adding TypeScript to React project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64720086/could-not-find-a-required-file-adding-typescript-to-react-project)

Comment: I think error is related to import statement, maybe your project is trying to import component from `./src/containers/ItemsHolder/ItemsHolder.js` and it does not find it because you have renamed it to .tsx

Comment: Yes, this is because I tired to do it this way before, but it does not find the file. I think the error happens when the compiling process happen but I can't find anything related to this on line. I was thinking it was an old version of react.

Comment: The link you followed is specifically for create-react-app, so it's not going to work "out of the box" for you. But, I think you are close by renaming everything to .tsx. You will likely have to modify your webpack config to use index.tsx instead of index.js as its entry point. Leave  your build.js and start.js as JS and check their contents for references that need to be updated to .tsx

Answer (score 0):

As per the react-scripts 2.10 you can add TypeScript to an existing project.

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest --dev
```

Comment: I have added this with npm, the error appears when I then run npm start to restar the server.

Answer (score 0):

Create a react-native app using : `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

Once its up and running, follow this [**link**](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native#adding-typescript) to add typescript the right way.

Comment: But this is to create a new project with react. I want to migrate the current project to it!

Comment: @CarlosEscobar Skip the initialising and pre-req part... I have updated the link in my solution. Check that out. Complete all the steps till the bottom the the page.